C Code trying to open a valid directory with opendir() ends with error "No such file or directory"
I am not able to figure out whats wrong with this simple code, so looking for C experts to guide here please :) The folder exist and have standard permissions set, even if I try to access D Drive root folder it doesn't work. I am testing this program on Windows 10, using WSL, and compiled program using "cc -std=c11 -o sample sample.c" and code compiled without errors. My code file "sample.c" is in a sub folder "D:\TopFolder\Test"
Here is my code and I am expecting code to list all files and directories under the path specified.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
    //const char *path = "D:\\TopFolder"; // this also did not work
    const char *path = "D:\\"; // Specify the directory path
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *entry;

    // Open the directory
    directory = opendir(path);
    if (directory == NULL) {
        printf("Attempting to open directory: %s\n", path);
        perror("Failed to open directory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // Exit with failure if unable to open directory
    }

    // Read entries from the directory
    printf("Contents of %s:\n", path);
    while ((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
        // Skip the "." and ".." entries
        if (entry->d_name[0] != '.') {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }
    }

    // Close the directory
    closedir(directory);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // Exit successfully
}

"icacls d:" in command line returns the following, if this helps -
d: BUILTIN\\Administrators:(F)  
BUILTIN\\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)  
NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM:(F)  
NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)  
NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users:(M)  
NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)  
BUILTIN\\Users:(RX)  
BUILTIN\\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)


Unrelated: Your check to "Skip the "." and ".." entries" also skips all other entries starting with .. If that's what you want, you should update the comment.

Try getcwd()


cc -std=c11 sample sample.c - this will try to use sample as input instead of writing the result to it. Add -o:
cc -std=c11 -o sample sample.c


D:\ isn't known to wsl. Use /mnt/d instead.


that was typo in my question, I am compiling with -o flag. As I said my code has no evident errors as such and compiles just fine. The issue is that it is not able to do what it is suppose to and fails at "directory = opendir(path);" line as directory is NULL and ends with error "No such file or directory"...

@rise.ashok Ok, but you must do both things I wrote in my answer and then it will work fine. Did you try that?

@rise.ashok It'll be hard to give you any more support if you don't respond. Did you follow my advice (both of them)? Did it work or not? If it didn't, how did the problem manifest itself?

Sorry I was travelling, will test this today. Thanks Ted.

1) cc -std=c11 -o sample sample.c
as I said above my code compiles fine without errors or warnings, and i used
cc -std=c11 -o sample sample.c to compile my program, so no issues there
2) D:\  v/s /mnt/d
Did not help "/mnt/d" is only when you are working in WSL console, not works in C code. e.g. if you want to change directory in WSL console you do something like this "cd /mnt/d/TopFolder" but not in C code.
Anyways I tried to change in code to see if it does any magic but no luck -
const char *path = "mnt/d/TopFolder";
Got same error "No such file or directory"

@rise.ashok You are wrong about not having to use /mnt/d from your C code that you compile with standard gcc or clang in WSL. You are also not doing what I said. mnt/d is a relative path and that's not what I said you should use. Details matter, so replace D:\ with /mnt/d and your program will work.

Sorry for  confusion, but I did not say that I did not use, I said "...I tried to change in code to see if it does any magic but no luck - const char *path = "mnt/d/TopFolder"; Got same error 'No such file or directory'". 
Now I see that the issue was the missing leading slash "/", so now I tried /mnt/d/TopFolder and it worked! Thanks a lot for making me think more :)

@rise.ashok You're welcome! I'm glad it worked out!
